# How to use useRef() for multiple components and to scroll down to a specific component when user clicks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 7 components on a website page with a navbar on the top. The navbar have 7 titles that representing those 7 components. Each component has complicated data structures and flows. What I want to achieve is; when a user clicks on one of navbar's title, it will scroll down to the specific components.

My questions;

1. How can I use useRef() for multiple components in React Typescript?
2. Is there any example that I can refer to?

Example code:

```js
const SectionOne = () => <div>Section One</div>
const SectionTwo = () => <div>Section Two</div>
const SectionThree = () => <div>Section Three</div>
const SectionFour = () => <div>Section Four</div>
const SectionFive = () => <div>Section Five</div>
const SectionSix = () => <div>Section Six</div>
const SectionSeven = () => <div>Section Seven</div>

const titlesArr = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven"]

const nav = () => {

return (
  <>
    {
      titlesArr.map((i) =>
        <p>{i}</p>
      
    }
  </>
);
}

const App = () => {

return (
  <Nav />
  <SectionOne />
  <SectionTwo />
  <SectionThree />
  <SectionFour />
  <SectionFive />
  <SectionSix />
  <SectionSeven />
);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with React, but you might want to consider giving the elements `id` values and then just using `<a href="#id">...</a>` to scroll to them using the browser's built-in handling. That also has the advantage of adding a history entry and providing a hash fragment in the URL that the use can bookmark.

If for some reason you don't want to do that, you can use seven `useRef` calls, either by repeating them in the code or by using a loop, to get seven refs. Then you can put them on the seven elements and, when a relevant navigation element is clicked, use the ref that relates to to scroll the element into view (for instance, using [`scrollInView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)):

```js
const { useRef } = React;

const NavBar = ({sections}) => {
    const scrollToSection = (event, ref) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        ref.current.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth",
        });
    };
    return <nav>
        {sections.map(({title, ref}) =>
            <a key={title} href={`#${title}`} onClick={(event) => scrollToSection(event, ref)}>
                {title}
            </a>
        )}
    </nav>;
};

const sectionTitles = [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    "D",
    "E",
    "F",
    "G",
];
const Example = () => {
    const sections = sectionTitles.map((title) => {
        return {title, ref: useRef(null)};
    });
    
    return <div>
        <NavBar sections={sections} />
        <main>
            {sections.map(({title, ref}) =>
                <section key={title} ref={ref}>
                    {title}
                </section>
            )}
        </main>
    </div>;
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
.render(<Example />);
```

```css
section {
    min-height: 20rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
nav a {
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

---

You've edited your question to show an MRE of what you currently have (although `App` has an error, you can't have adjacent JSX elements without some kind of wrapper). I would take those individual `SectionOne`, `SectionTwo`, etc. variables and put them in an array (not unlike the above), but keep reading if you don't want to do that. You'll also need to wrap your sections in a call to `forwardRef` and accept the `ref` parameter ([details here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)):

```js
const { useRef, forwardRef } = React;

// Since you'll need *something* that relates titles to sections,
// and you already had an array of titls, it seems reasonable to use
// an array rather than individual `SectionOne`, `SectionTwo`, etc. 
// constants for that. But you can have them and then repeat them below
// for the `Section` values if you prefer.
const sections = [
    {title: "One",   Section: forwardRef((_, ref) => <div ref={ref}>Section One</div>)},
    {title: "Two",   Section: forwardRef((_, ref) => <div ref={ref}>Section Two</div>)},
    {title: "Three", Section: forwardRef((_, ref) => <div ref={ref}>Section Three</div>)},
    {title: "Four",  Section: forwardRef((_, ref) => <div ref={ref}>Section Four</div>)},
    {title: "Five",  Section: forwardRef((_, ref) => <div ref={ref}>Section Five</div>)},
    {title: "Six",   Section: forwardRef((_, ref) => <div ref={ref}>Section Six</div>)},
    {title: "Seven", Section: forwardRef((_, ref) => <div ref={ref}>Section Seven</div>)},
];

// If you need the `titlesArr` for something:
const titlesArr = sections.map(({title}) => title);

const Nav = ({sections, refs}) => {
    const scrollTo = (ref) => {
        ref.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
    };
    return sections.map(({title, ref}) =>
        <p key={title} onClick={() => scrollTo(ref)}>{title}</p>
    );
};

const App = () => {
    const sectionsWithRefs = sections.map(section => ({
        ...section,
        ref: useRef(null),
    }));
    return <div>
        <Nav sections={sectionsWithRefs} />
        {sectionsWithRefs.map(({title, Section, ref}) => <Section key={title} ref={ref} />)}
        {/* Just for the example, a spacer so we have room to scroll down to sections */}
        <div style={{height: "50rem"}} />
    </div>;
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

If you really want those individual `SectionOne`, `SectionTwo`, etc.:

```js
const { useRef, forwardRef } = React;

const SectionOne   = forwardRef((_, ref) => <div ref={ref}>Section One</div>);
const SectionTwo   = forwardRef((_, ref) => <div ref={ref}>Section Two</div>);
const SectionThree = forwardRef((_, ref) => <div ref={ref}>Section Three</div>);
const SectionFour  = forwardRef((_, ref) => <div ref={ref}>Section Four</div>);
const SectionFive  = forwardRef((_, ref) => <div ref={ref}>Section Five</div>);
const SectionSix   = forwardRef((_, ref) => <div ref={ref}>Section Six</div>);
const SectionSeven = forwardRef((_, ref) => <div ref={ref}>Section Seven</div>);

// Since you'll need *something* that relates titles to sections,
// and you already had an array of titls, it seems reasonable to use
// an array rather than individual `SectionOne`, `SectionTwo`, etc. 
// constants for that. But you can have them and then repeat them below
// for the `Section` values if you prefer.
const sections = [
    {title: "One",   Section: SectionOne},
    {title: "Two",   Section: SectionTwo},
    {title: "Three", Section: SectionThree},
    {title: "Four",  Section: SectionFour},
    {title: "Five",  Section: SectionFive},
    {title: "Six",   Section: SectionSix},
    {title: "Seven", Section: SectionSeven},
];

// If you need the `titlesArr` for something:
const titlesArr = sections.map(({title}) => title);

const Nav = ({sections, refs}) => {
    const scrollTo = (ref) => {
        ref.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
    };
    return sections.map(({title, ref}) =>
        <p key={title} onClick={() => scrollTo(ref)}>{title}</p>
    );
};

const App = () => {
    const sectionsWithRefs = sections.map(section => ({
        ...section,
        ref: useRef(null),
    }));
    let n = 0;
    return <div>
        <Nav sections={sectionsWithRefs} />
        {/* I would use `sectionsWithRefs` as in the previous example, but
        if you _really_ don't want to: */}
        <SectionOne   ref={sectionsWithRefs[n++].ref} />
        <SectionTwo   ref={sectionsWithRefs[n++].ref} />
        <SectionThree ref={sectionsWithRefs[n++].ref} />
        <SectionFour  ref={sectionsWithRefs[n++].ref} />
        <SectionFive  ref={sectionsWithRefs[n++].ref} />
        <SectionSix   ref={sectionsWithRefs[n++].ref} />
        <SectionSeven ref={sectionsWithRefs[n++].ref} />
        {/* Just for the example, a spacer so we have room to scroll down to sections */}
        <div style={{height: "50rem"}} />
    </div>;
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```